# Javascript function argument is inputting as a 0 instead of a 1

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm having a problem with a JS range function I'm making for a codewars kata. Whenever I only have two arguments instead of 3 my start gets inputted as a 0 instead of a 1. I've found out that this is because of my arguments.lenth==1 if statement, but that shouldn't apply at all! This is my range statement:

```
function range(start, end, step) {
  if(arguments.length<3) {
  if(arguments.length==2)  step=1;
  if(arguments.length==1)  end=start; start=0; step=1;
  }
  if(end < start)  return [];

  arr = [];

  while(start < end) {
    arr.push(start);
    start+=step;
  }
  return arr;;  
}
```

When I try and input:

```
range(1,11);
```

The start of my range becomes 0 and the end becomes 11, yet when I input:

```
range(1, 11, 1);
```

Can you guys please point me in the right direction? For the life of me I can't figure it out!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I can't format code nicely in the comments, I'll put it as an answer.

Here is how the engine interprets your code:

```
if(arguments.length<3) {
    if(arguments.length==2)
        step=1;
    if(arguments.length==1)
        end=start;
    start=0;
    step=1;
}
```

[The syntax for an `if` statement is:](https://es5.github.io/#x12.5)

```
if ( Expression ) Statement
```

So you see, the `if` statement only accepts a **single** statement as "body".

`end=start;` is an expression statement, so that becomes the "body" of the `if` statement. The following expression statements (`start=0; step=1;`) are on the same "level" as the `if` statement and are just executed after it.

If you want the body of the `if` statement to consist of multiple statements, you have to use a [*block statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) as "body" and put those statements inside of the block.

---

Indentation and whitespace between statements/expressions has no meaning in JavaScript.

Comment: It's also a great example of why always using braces with an `if` statement is just a safer way to code as it prevents accidental mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this:

```
if(arguments.length==1)
{
  end=start; start=0; step=1;
}
```

I like curly braces lined up vertically.